# QGIS raster buffer by cell value

Tags: qgis, raster, buffer

Is it possible to buffer a raster in QGIS based on cell value? I want to be able to model the theoretical falling zones from tree height data (1x1 resolution LiDAR data) from tree canopy cover extent data.

There seems to be an option in the SAGA tools to assign the buffer value to 'cell value'. I was hoping to be able to do this in QGIS interface without 3rd party tools, as the SAGA tool (raster buffer) is problematic in the current QGIS version.

Comment: Did you try Processing Toolbox > GRASS > Raster > r. buffer ?

Comment: Maybe you can expand on your question. It's not clear whether you want to buffer the entire area, or do it tree by tree.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. The Grass r.buffer just allows to buffer each cell by a single value (or a series). I want to buffer each cell based on its value and then have a single output raster with value 1 for each pixel affected by the buffer operation. And value for say 2 for all original pixels with buffer applied and value 0 for pixels not affected. Saga ‘raster buffer’ does this, but I have to run this from within Saga NextGen provider plugin does not work to provide a geotiff output. I can run it from within Saga GUI but I am limited due to the file processing size in Saga.